# Understanding the SAS PDV in by-group processing

Tags: sas

While I've read quite a bit about conceptualizing the Program Data Vector when using a SAS data step, I still don't understand how the PDV works when there is by group processing. For example if I have the dataset `olddata`

```
 GROUP   VAL
 A       10
 A        5
 B       20
```

And I call a datastep on it with a by statement, such as:

```
data newdata;
set olddata;
by group;
...
run;
```

then the compiler adds two temporary variables to the PDV: first.group and last.group. When you read any tutorial on the PDV it will tell you that on the first pass of the SET statement, the PDV will look like:

```
_N_    _ERROR_   FIRST.GROUP   LAST.GROUP   GROUP   VAL
  1          0             1            0       A    10
```

and that LAST.GROUP is zero because observation 1 is not the last observation in group A.

Herein lies my question: How does SAS know that this is not the last observation?

If SAS is processing `olddata` row-by-row, how is the PDV aware that the next row holds another group A observation instead of a new group? In other words, it seems like SAS must be using information from previous or future rows to update the `FIRST` and `LAST` variables, but I'm not sure how. Is there some trick in how the PDV retains values from row to row when the `BY` statement is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS actually looks ahead to the next record to see if it should set LAST.(var) or not.  I haven't been able to find an article explaining that in any detail, unfortunately.  I was a bit disappointed to see that even papers like http://www.wuss.org/proceedings09/09WUSSProceedings/papers/ess/ESS-Li1.pdf just gloss over how LAST is detemined.

SAS also looks ahead to see if the END= variable should be set, when specified, and a few other things.  It's not just using metadata to determine those; you can remove or modify records without modifying the metadata, and it will still work - and SQL tables that don't have the usual SAS metadata will still allow you to perform normal BY group processing and such.

The FIRST variable doesn't need a look-behind, of course; it remembers where it was after all.

Edit: I crossposted this to SAS-L, and got the same answer - there doesn't seem to be any documentation of the subject, but it must read ahead.  See http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A1=ind1303a&L=sas-l#8 for example.

Edit2: From SAS-L, Dan Nordlund linked to a paper that confirms this. http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/222-2012.pdf

The paper's logic that confirms the lookahead - look at the number of observations read from the data set.

```
DATA DS_Sample1;          
Input Sum_Var 
Product;     
Cards;                  
100 3                   
100 2                   
100 1                   
;                 
*With BY statement - reads 3 observations even though it stops after 2.;
DATA DS_Sample2;    
  Set DS_Sample1;           
  by Sum_Var;               
  cnt+1; If CNT > 1 then stop;
Run;
*no BY statement - reads 2 observations as expected;
DATA DS_Sample2;    
  Set DS_Sample1;           
  cnt+1; If CNT > 1 then stop;
Run;
* END statement - again, a lookahead;
DATA DS_Sample2;    
  Set DS_Sample1 end=eof;
  cnt+1; If CNT > 1 then stop;
Run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe. We've probably found similar things. It's disappointing that so many descriptions of the data step processing of the PDV are clearly incomplete. Presumably there's some sort of read-ahead buffer separate from the PDV, but like you say, there don't seem to be any good descriptions of what's happening.

Comment: Edited with a link from the SAS-L discussion.

Comment: Thanks for following up. It seems strange to me, then, that there's so much gnashing of teeth about having `lead()`-like functions in SAS. The usual rationale is SAS's by-row processing model. But if there's a mechanism for read-aheads, it seems that `lead()` or similar functions ought to be possible using that mechanism.

Comment: I think there's a difference between looking ahead to see if a particular value is there, and actually reading in the whole record.  (Since SAS stores data in a rectangular format, ie, with no VARCHAR type variable, every variable is in a predictable location for every observation, it's trivial to look for a particular value; but looking for the entire record would be significantly more work.)  FWIW, LAG() doesn't work that way either; and LEAD is trivial to implement in the datastep (side by side merge, with the second datset having FIRSTOBS=2).

Comment: That's a great point, but then the example from the paper you link seems odd. If SAS is just going to a specific memory location to check a value, it seems strange for the log to report it read `x+1` observations (i.e., if it's not reading in the whole record). Maybe I'm not thinking about the example correctly, though.

Comment: It's certainly looking at the next observation, but it's not reading the whole observation into the PDV.